# How can we derive the schrodinger wave equation?

Tags: schroedinger-equation

How can we derive the Schrodinger wave equation with simplified explanation?

Comment: You cannot derive it.

Comment: One can't derive Newton's laws, either, or Maxwell's equations for that matter. The Schroedinger equation is simply the first time that many people get the idea that it should be derivable from some first principles. To me that's a surprising psychological observation and I am not excluding myself from this group, by the way, because that is what happened to me, too. After some wrestling with the problem one does notice, of course, that one may not have had the same question in high school about Newton. And that's when it dawned on me that the question does not have an answer.

Comment: Thanks CuriousOne for the reply but I speculate, that if some equation can not e derived, then how was it framed in the first place.